# Generate link in Web API using Url.Link

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core WebAPI that has a route. In the return result, I am embedding links. I'm using Url.Link() to generate these links, but the link created is not generating a proper URL.

Example code:

```
    [HttpGet( Name = "GetResultsRoute")]
  public IActionResult GetResults([FromQuery] AuthorResourceParameters parameters)
  {
     ...
     var myUrl = Url.Link("GetResultsRoute", new { pageNumber = parameters.PageNumber,pageSize = parameters.PageSize });
  .............
```

The URL generated will be something like:

"http://localhost:10010/api/authors?pageNumber=1\u0026pageSize=2"

What I want is:

"http://localhost:10010/api/authors?pageNumber=1&pageSize=2"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you viewing the result? `\u0026` is the unicode representation of `&`

Comment: Does your link works when you put it in your browser? Link with \u0026 is encoded link. What you can do is System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str); But I think it is not neccessary

Comment: no the link not working in the browser

Comment: It could work well in my project.What browser did you use and what is your version of asp.net core?

Comment: ASP.net core 3.1 my browser is firefox and chrome by I didn't use both I use postman for requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue and I changed from using `System.Text.Json` to using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package. I then used the `newtonsoft` method `JsonConverter.SerializeObject(<myObj>)` and found my UrlLink creates a working pagination URI within my Response Header. Now "&" appears where I need it.